# How can I remove the last line of a note in evernote?

Tags: applescript, evernote

I want to remove the last line of each note in evernote.
It's easy to do with shell scripts, e.g. use wc to get the length of the note, and then use head to print all lines but the last one, or with sed.
But I can't find a way to stream the contents of the note to the shell.
I've tried this (and many others)

`do shell script "echo <<<" & noteText`

Any ideas?

Here's the whole script

```
tell application "Evernote"
set noteList to find notes ""
repeat with i from 1 to number of items in noteList
    set this_note to item i of noteList
    set this_note_text to ENML content of this_note
    my removeLastLine(this_note_text)
end repeat
end tell

on removeLastLine(note)
set countCmd to "wc <<< " & note
(* do shell script countCmd *)
set noteText to note as string
log noteText
do shell script "echo <<<" & noteText
(* set newNote to do shell script "head -(size - 1)" *)
end removeLastLine
```

Answer (score 1):

**OK, here is my solution using the HTML of the Evernote Note**.
CAUTION:  Any images or attachments in Note may be lost.

Given this as the HTML of the Note:

```html
<div id="en-note"><div>2019-02-02  21:47 GMT-6</div><div><br/></div><div>REF:  <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54485617/how-can-i-remove-the-last-line-of-a-note-in-evernote">How can I remove the last line of a note in evernote?</a></div><div><br/></div><div>This is a test.</div><div><br/></div><ol><li>One</li><li>two</li><li>three</li></ol><div><br/></div><div>This is the last line where X&gt;Y, A&lt;B, and a path of /dir1/dir2/file.text.<br/></div></div>
```

This AppleScript will remove the last user line.
NOTE:  I am still testing the RegEx for this, so this should be considered BETA/DRAFT version.  But it should be good enough to get you started.

Please let us know if this works for you, or you have questions/issues.

```applescript
property ptyScriptName : "Remove Last User Text Line from Evernote Note"
property ptyScriptVer : "1.0"
property ptyScriptDate : "2019-02-03"
property ptyScriptAuthor : "JMichaelTX"

use AppleScript version "2.5" -- El Capitan (10.11) or later
use framework "Foundation"
use scripting additions

--- RegEx to Find Last User Text Line ---
## (<div>(?!.+?<div>).+?<\/div>)(<\/div>)$
set reFind to "(<div>(?!.+?<div>).+?<\\/div>)(<\\/div>)$"


tell application "Evernote"
  set noteList to selection
  set oNote to item 1 of noteList
  set bodyHTML to HTML content of oNote

  set bodyNewHTML to my regexChange(reFind, "", bodyHTML)
  set HTML content of oNote to bodyNewHTML
end tell


--~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
on regexChange(pFindStr, pReplaceStr, pSourceStr) -- @RegEX @Change @Replace @Strings @ASObjC
  --–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––
  (*  VER: 2.0    2018-07-06
    PURPOSE:  Change ALL Occurances of pFindStr into pReplaceStr in pSourceStr
    METHOD:    Uses ASObjC RegEx (which is based on ICU Regex)
    PARAMETERS:
      • pFindStr    | text |  RegEx Pattern to Find
      • pReplaceStr | text |  Replace string which
          • May contain these RegEx MetaChars:  
                \\n, \\r, \\t for linefeed, return, and tab
                $<CG>, where <CG> is Capture Group number
      • pSourceStr   | text |  Source String to be searched

    RETURNS:  Revised String with all changes that were found.

    AUTHOR:  JMichaelTX -- with help from NigelGarvey
    ## REQUIRES:  use framework "Foundation"
    REF:  
      1.  2018-07-06, NigelGarvey, Late Night Software Ltd.
          ASObjC RegEx Change Handler
          http://forum.latenightsw.com/t/asobjc-regex-change-handler/1395/10
      2.  ICU RegEx Users Guide
          http://userguide.icu-project.org/strings/regexp
  --–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––
  *)
  set nsCurApp to current application

  -- Replace any backslash-n sequences in the replace string with actual character --

  set nsReplaceStr to nsCurApp's NSString's stringWithString:pReplaceStr
  set nsReplaceStr to nsReplaceStr's stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:"\\n" withString:(linefeed)
  set nsReplaceStr to nsReplaceStr's stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:"\\r" withString:(return)
  set nsReplaceStr to nsReplaceStr's stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:"\\t" withString:(tab)

  set nsSourceStr to nsCurApp's NSString's stringWithString:pSourceStr

  set nsSourceStr to (nsSourceStr's stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:pFindStr withString:nsReplaceStr options:(nsCurApp's NSRegularExpressionSearch) range:{0, nsSourceStr's |length|()})

  return nsSourceStr as text

end regexChange
--~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ END of Handler ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Answer (score 0):

**This is NOT a solution.  It is guidance/suggestions that don't fit well in a Comment line.**

**Your task is much more complex that it might appear.**  You have two major challenges to overcome:
(1) Removing the last line of user text (as opposed to the last line of the ENML text)
(2) Updating the existing Note ENML.

`#1` can be overcome.  The last line of ENML text contains XML tags that you do NOT want to remove. It is NOT the same as the last line of user text that you view in the Evernote app.  Here is an example ENML text, which has 3 lines of text.  The last user line is embedded in the last ENML line, which has several tags.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE en-note SYSTEM "http://xml.evernote.com/pub/enml2.dtd">
<en-note><div>2019-02-02  21:47 GMT-6</div><div><br/></div><div>This is a test.</div><div><br/></div><div><ol><li>One</li><li>two</li><li>three</li></ol><div><br/></div></div><div>this is the last line.</div><div><br/></div></en-note>
```

`#2` is a huge challenge.  You can *change* the Note HTML, but NOT the Note ENML through scripting.  And the HTML will NOT include any references to embedded images and attachments.  The only workaround I have seen is to edit the actual file buried in the Evernote data folders in the `~/Library/Application Support/com.evernote.Evernote` folder (known as the "Evernote Database folder").  OTOH, if you want to create a new Note using the modified ENML text, then that can be easily done.  Open the Evernote Scripting Dictionary from Script Editor to see what is available.

If you just want to create a NEW Note, please update your question to indicate such.

If I have more time tomorrow, I'll examine further.

---

**UPDATE 2019-02-03  18:17 GMT-6**

So now the OP has stated that he can work with using only HTML.  So here's a example HTML from an EN Note

```html
<div id="en-note"><div>2019-02-02  21:47 GMT-6</div><div><br/></div><div>REF:  <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54485617/how-can-i-remove-the-last-line-of-a-note-in-evernote">How can I remove the last line of a note in evernote?</a></div><div><br/></div><div>This is a test.</div><div><br/></div><ol><li>One</li><li>two</li><li>three</li></ol><div><br/></div><div>this is the last line.</div><div><br/></div></div>
```

The last USER line is:
`This is a test.`

The challenge is that there can be other non-text stuff after this line before the final `</div>`

I'm working on the RegEx now.  If any of you RegEx gurus out there see the solution for this, please jump in.  It's too bad we can use the Web page DOM for this.  That would be much easier than RegEx.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the elaborate suggestion already. I just randomly picked the ENML format. So if changing HTML is easier, then that's certainly possible.

Comment: Using HTML is much easier.  You can get, and SET, the Note body using HTML.  We can use RegEx to remove the last user text line, but it turning out to be a bigger challenge than I thought, IF we have to allow for other stuff (like `<BR>`) after the text.  Can you please post a real-world example of the HTML of the EN Notes of interest where you want to remove the last user line.  I'll update my above answer with the example I'm working with.

Comment: Hi Michael, thanks a lot for so much help, really appreciated. Unfortunately it doesn't work yet. Here are the last few lines of the post which is picked up by the script. They are exactly the same before and after the script.
`<div><br/></div>
Evernote tags to be used by bear:</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>`

Btw. the text "Evernote tags to be used by bear:" followed by some tags, is the line that I want to remove. That can make the regex somewhat simpler. But whatever I try, the line does not get removed.